# Selenium RC in C# How to Validate Page Source Code

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, selenium-rc

Hello I've been assigned a QA ticket to validate a javascript code snippet on a page. The best way of doing this of course is to view source on page and look for the code.

However I have to do this on 20 different locales, and I've been using Selenium RC with .NET driver handily.

Is there a functionality in Selenium to check for page source code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `getHtmlSource` command, but what you're asking for isn't really as easy as it sounds.  Unless you just want to look and say "Yup, the  script is there!".